# C# WebBrowser select radio button

Tags: c#, html

I am having a problem in C#. I'm trying to click and select a radio button on a website but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Here's the HTML from my site:

```
<tr class="trwc">
    <td id="row1" class="SelectBoxRow" >
        <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="valg" value="1"  /> 
        <strong>Option1</strong>
    </td>
</tr>
                    
<tr class="trwc">
    <td id="row2" class="SelectBoxRow" >
        <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="valg" value="2"  /> 
        Option2
    </td>
</tr>
                    
<tr class="trwc">
    <td id="row3" class="SelectBoxRow" >
        <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="valg" value="3"  /> 
        Option3
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want my code to click/select the radio with value 3.

I have tried this without any success:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("valg")[0].InvokeMember("click");
```

I could tell that code wouldn't work before I tried it, but I can't figure how to make it work properly.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works, but in your HTML you have

```
style="display:none"
```

for the radioButtons, so you cannot click them.

Also, if you want to select the one with `value = 3` you would have to change your code to

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("valg")[2].InvokeMember("click")
```

so the index points to the third radio button.

Or if you are not sure about the index of the value 3 radio, or it could change, you could do something like this:

```
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("valg"))
{
  if (el.GetAttribute("value") == "3")
  {
    el.InvokeMember("click");
  }
}
```

or with LINQ

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("valg").OfType<HtmlElement>().First(el => el.GetAttribute("value") == "3").InvokeMember("click");
```